# Are these proofs of convergence sufficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have to series which we want to test for convergence. The series and my attempts below.

> 1. $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x+1}{x^3+4} $

$\dfrac{x+1}{x^3+4} = \dfrac{x}{x^3+4} + \dfrac{1}{x^3+4} = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + \dfrac{1}{x}} + \dfrac{1}{x^3+4}$

Since $\dfrac{1}{x^2} > \dfrac{x}{x^3+4}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\dfrac{1}{x^3} > \dfrac{1}{x^3+4}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and we know that  $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2} $ and $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^3}$ both converge, so must the sum of these limits and thus so must  $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x+1}{x^3+4} $, by the comparison test.

> 2. $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{3^{-x}\cdot x}{x+1} $

We know that  $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} 3^{-x}\cdot x = \dfrac{3}{4} $ and also that $3^{-x}\cdot x >  \dfrac{3^{-x}\cdot x}{x+1} $ for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$, so by the comparison test  $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{3^{-x}\cdot x}{x+1} $ converges too.

Answer (score 0):

The series converges. 
Indeed:$$\dfrac{x+1}{x^3+4}\sim_{\infty}\frac {1}{x^2}$$
that converges